# How and by what should I create plugin to Firefox?

Tags: firefox, plugins

I'd like to write a plugin for Firefox with the idea of taking HTML code user is presently onto, process it and send it to external php script.

How would you proceed? What programming languages can I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a wealth of information available online to help you create Firefox extensions.

Here are some good ones:

> [Firefox Extension Development Tutorial :: Overview](http://www.rietta.com/firefox/Tutorial/overview.html)
>   [How To Develop A Firefox Extension](http://www.robertnyman.com/2009/01/24/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)
>   [Getting started with extension development](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_started_with_extension_development)

Comment: @Hare But that's pages for extensions or addons, not for Plugins, aren't they?